# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm new to React-Native and trying to start with it by following a beginner's tutorial. I've followed the tutorial and created a "Header" component and try to export and import it and eventually use it. Unfortunately I get an error: Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object.
I went across these two questions:

1. [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)
2. [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501856/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

But none of them helped me to solve my issue.

These are my files and their contents:

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

App.android.js

```
// Import section
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

// create a component
const App = () => (
    <Header />
);

// Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

header.js

```
// Import labraries for making a component
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

// Make a component
const Header = () => {
    return <Text>Albums</Text>
};

// Make the component available to other parts of the app
export default Header;
```

I've also tried to import header like this (but it didn't help):

```
import { Header } from './src/components/header';
```

I would really appreciate any help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance :)

P.S
I'm using React-Native version 0.49.1

Comment: Can you check your packager output? if there is anything paste here..

Comment: hi, the packager output is the output of react-native run-android? or the output of the nodejs window?

Comment: I've never seen an index.js without a `render()` method in react native. Is this all of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it up, the problem was that I registered App twice:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

Once in index.js and the second time in App.android.js.
I solved the error by removing the registration from index.js.

Thanks for the helpers anyway :)

Comment: Easy to miss. Everyone else did ha.

Answer (score 0):

Change this form :

```
import { Header } from './src/components/header';
```

to :

```
import  Header  from './src/components/header';
```

In index.js change :

```
import App from './App';
```

to

```
import App from './App.android';
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: As I wrote, I've tried both options but none of them solved the error.

Comment: tried what you wrote but didn't solved the error yet